# How to "charm" King Mardokh?

Tags: moon-hunters

Multiple times when I played this game lately, I've been told that I can talk to Mardokh and convince him to not be the rude jerk he is. However, even with 40 charisma and Seductive, he does not give attention to my fabulous Enkidu. What should I do ? Is this insight from my character mean I must find him before the last fight ?

Answer (score -1):

History can change according to the places you visit and the people you talk to. To convince Mardokh, I think he had to enter the temples of the sun and not fight with the cult of the sun. What if I can tell you with total certainty is that I never raised the level of the charisma in any of my characters, so I do not know if he will have total relationship with the things that happen during the game. Or at least you do not have to level them so much. It depends on the terrains where you can find certain things. As for example the temples of the sun are usually found in desert steppes.

Comment: Uh not sure I actually understand. You mean I should visit the sun cult base before the last day, not attack any of them and go talk to him ?